# IPhone SendDelegateMessage failed to return after waiting 10 Secs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, deadlock

I keep getting the following message from my iPhone 3.0 when trying to convert a large NSData object into base64Encoding for http transmission :

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

If you were not using the touch screen for this entire interval (which can prolong this wait), please file a bug.

I am using synchronous request and touch screen will be frozen with only UIProgressView displaying status while uploading data. 
Anyone have any good idea how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: if you have a synchronous request, when the web view attempts to call your delegate it won't respond. I'm pretty sure that's what this message is.

Comment: no - it means: i called a delegate and it takes too long and I can't continue displaying HTML or running JS

Answer (score 3):

As it says: you take too long ;D
web view to english: " i called a delegate and it takes too long and I can't continue displaying HTML or running JS"

don't block the web view or it will complain after a while...

so doing a synchronous request? on the main thread? never do that

**Better way:**

```
- webView:... {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
          //DO LONG RUNNING IN BG

          dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              //update UI
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the `UIWebView` then we need to do this first before moving to the next view

```
webView.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: You are right but this nowhere near the answer to this issue. that merly prevents a bad access