# Xcode 8 locks up my app with the following message

Tags: firebase, sprite-kit, admob, xcode8, firebase-analytics

> 2016-10-02 17:08:00.090910 Brain Cracker Memory Game[550:50210] WF:
>   _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
>    2016-10-02 17:08:18.511075 Brain Cracker Memory Game[550:50210] void
>   SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate
>   (webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource:) failed to return
>   after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

I am using the latest admob sdk for ads and for analytics(firebase).  App works perfectly in debug mode but if I run in release mode or in the store, it freezes the app with this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPhone SendDelegateMessage failed to return after waiting 10 Secs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618727/iphone-senddelegatemessage-failed-to-return-after-waiting-10-secs)

Comment: Ended up resolving this issue. We had an infinite loop condition that locked up the app. Had nothing to do with the messages above other then the app was locked up.

Comment: post an answer so people in the future can see if that is their issue.